# Need a header file that undefs all defines in windows.h

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

To be tidy, I want to `#undef` everything defined in `windows.h`.

E.G:

```
namespace os_stuff
{
    #include <windows.h>

    // ARGH! Macros everywhere!

    // at least I can keep the rest of the API in here
}

// include a bunch of files here that use the Windows API through os_stuff

namespace os_stuff
{
    #include <unwindows.h> // <- #undefs all that was #defined in windows.h
}

// All clean, as though windows.h was never here. Though os_stuff, used nowhere else,
// still has all of the API declarations in it (which is OK).
```

Comment: I laughed when I read the title, but it really does have meaning when you consider the Windows API.

Comment: I thought it was weird myself when I asked it. However, as you are aware, their C API isn't at all polite when it comes to macros. "min" and "max" are examples, albeit easily-remedied ones (must always NOMINMAX before windows.h, or a kitten dies).

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do that -- or even a complicated one.  The only way I can see is the outrageously tedious, error-prone approach of manually building your own unwindows.h that #undefs every single macro in the entire Windows SDK header file set.  And if I actually saw someone do that, I would either fire them or change careers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more sensible to split the API-using stuff and the API-allergic stuff into separate source modules?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Not when you need things like InterlockedIncrement64 at the header level. Though that is technically in WinBase.h, many, many things break when trying to include that file by itself.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to keep the API function declarations but not the macros.  One issue is that a function (such as InterlockedIncrement64) might be a declaration in one version of the SDK and a macro in the next, or it may depend on the architecture.

Comment: Perhaps you could pass a file containing just `#include <windows.h>` through the preprocessor, remove the `#define` commands, and use that as your header file?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Interesting idea, though I don't know of any preprocessor tool or feature of any tool that could produce such a list of macro symbols.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I considered the same solution, but what you end up with is being forced to use meaningless numeric constants in place of named constants.  (Everyone knows that 0x00000001 means FILE_SHARE_READ, right?  Clearly, the solution is far worse than the problem.)  You could, of course, build a tool to parse the headers and generate a header file you can live with, but frankly, I think it's totally a fool's errand.  I understand the goal of i_photon's question but I think it's completely unattainable.

Comment: A tool for this purpose needs to exist somewhere... There are a large number of equally rude header files out there I've found impossible to work with due to severe macro namespace pollution. Perhaps a simple-to-use #pragma-based feature would solve the problem without obfuscating the build process (e.g. #pragma macros(push), followed by a #pragma macros(pop)).

Comment: Is the only purpose for this "to be tidy"?  Seems like an awful lot of work for very little benefit.  Sometimes it's easier to work with the system than against it; I suspect this is one of those times.

Comment: @Luke: There are an awful number of surprises when porting a Posix application to Windows. For example, there is a "#define small char" somewhere buried in Windows.h. This means that you get funny errors when your code contains a variable named "small"! Or the #define for GetObject (to just mention the issues that tripped me up the last days). Really, what were they thinking when they "designed" this mess? It would be soo nice to have a pragma that removed all unnecessary defines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than undefing everything, avoid defining them in the first place.  You can do this by explicitly passing the first part of your module (as a separate source file) through the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) and including the preprocessor output, rather than the original source code, in your module's main source file.

I tried this out using Visual Studio 2010.  For my trial, I created three source files.  This is headers.cpp, analogous to the first part of your sample code:

```
namespace os_stuff
{
#undef _MSC_EXTENSIONS
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#include <windows.h>
}

#include "xyzzy.h"
```

The `#undef _MSC_EXTENSIONS` is to prevent the inclusion of `sourceannotations.h`, because that file generates errors when included from inside a namespace.

This is xyzzy.h, to demonstrate "include a bunch of files here" from your sample code:

```
os_stuff::DWORD myFunction(os_stuff::HANDLE h);
```

And this is test.cpp, analogous to the "all clean" part of your sample code:

```
#include "headers.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  os_stuff::DWORD UNALIGNED;
  os_stuff::HANDLE h = 0;
  UNALIGNED = myFunction(h);
  return UNALIGNED;
}
```

Note that we're using UNALIGNED as a variable name, not because it makes sense, but just as an example of something that won't work if you've included `windows.h` directly (because it expands to the __unaligned keyword).

From a Visual Studio 2010 command line, create `headers.h` like this:

```
cl /P headers.cpp /Fiheaders.h
```

The /P option is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6).

You can then compile `test.cpp` in the usual way:

```
cl test.cpp
```

(Obviously in this case the program won't link because we haven't defined myFunction, but it compiles perfectly happily.)

With a bit of fiddling around it shouldn't be too hard to automate the building of `headers.h` rather than doing it from the command line.

In some C++ compilers the preprocessor is actually a separate executable (this was the traditional model) but if not there should still be an option to just run the preprocessor without invoking the compiler.

Comment: Show me a non-trivial Windows app, either GUI or console, that uses such a scheme and isn't completely incomprehensible and unmaintainable.

Comment: I forgot MSC could do that. The problem is that, as Carey Gregory mentioned in a comment earlier, all the macros I need in the interim disappear (e.g: I need WM_INPUT and WM_DEVICECHANGE amongst other things).

Comment: I now realized that you included what would be the code that uses the API in the same file that is preprocessed (so, I was wrong in assuming the macros would be unavailable). I tried the same thing and it took me about 5 minutes to set it up. Yes, that would work, but I have a lot of other such files to deal with -- setting this up for all of them could take me weeks (mostly having to either rename/move files, or repoint includes).

Comment: @CareyGregory: it does what the OP asked for.  Whether that is sensible is another question entirely!  I think that in very rare cases it *might* be, if the bulk of the code is non-OS-specific but needs a few bits of glue, and if the Windows SDK macros actually do conflict with the existing code.  (Unlikely, admittedly, unless the originally programmer liked leading underscores a lot.)

Comment: @i_photon: "setting this up for all of them could take me weeks" - I don't doubt it.  I'm guessing that just putting up with the macros doesn't look all that bad now, huh? :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: We have a lot of code with leading underscores, though thankfully they all start with our company acronym -- so no conflicts. The biggest issues aren't really with windows.h, but a lot of our legacy code that used to exist in independent modules (which I have to rewrite anyway...). I was hoping that by asking a windows-related question on this site I might get a useful answer sooner than later :P